# What is the best design for Dojo app structure

Tags: dojo

Okay, so I think I can better articulate what it is I want to accomplish.

In order to save time and code writing, I would like to create a module/widget that has other dijits in it such as BorderContainer, TabContainer, and more.  I would like the module to be programmatic rather than template based.

In index.php I would like to load my application simply like this...

[image]

My first question is...

Is this the correct way to go about creating a module with other widgets/modules in it?

My next question is...

What should my SuperScreen.js structure look like?

Right now, it looks like this...

[image]

But clearly this will not work.

The reference to "bc" is in the constructor so naturally it is not available to the placeAt function call.

Should my border container be in the Constructor or elsewhere?

It seems as though the declare function allows for inheritance.  I am confused as I don't want to inherit from BorderContainer, I just want to use it.

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/205233)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First question: short answer is yes,

Then to make bc visible to placeAt, you could do this in SuperScreen.js:

```
define([...], function(...){
    var bc;
    return declare(null, {
        constructor: function(args){
            bc = new BorderContainer(...);
        },
        placeAt: function(){
            bc.placeAt(...);
            ...
        }
    });
});
```

Alternatively you could do this:

```
    define([...], function(...){
        return declare(null, {
        constructor: function(args){
            this.bc = new BorderContainer(...);
        },
        placeAt: function(){
            this.bc.placeAt(...);
            ...
        }
    });
});
```

In the first solution, bc is a static variable, visible to both constructor and placeAt. Then it is shared among all the instances of SuperScreen, which makes no harm if SuperScreen will be instantiated only once. Still you should rather use the second solution, at least "just in case". If you plan to instantiate SuperScreen more than once, then solution 2 is mandatory, where there is one bc (one distinct BorderContainer) per SuperScreen instance.

This is why in situations where only one instance is needed, I prefer a module that returns a plain object, rather than a class as I feel it transmits the proper semantics (a class which is instantiated once does not really need to be a class and dojo/define allows this, so I'm using it !), and in the end it results in simpler code:

- in index.php:

  ```
  require ([SuperScreen], function(){
      SuperScreen.prepare();
      superScreen.placeAt(document.body);
  });
  ```
- in SuperScreen.js:

  ```
  define([...], function(...){
      return {
          prepare: function(args){
              this.bc = new BorderContainer(...);
              ...
          },
          placeAt: function(){
              this.bc.placeAt(...);
              ...
      }
  });
  ```

To answer your question "should your BorderContainer be in the constructor or elsewhere ?":

- yourSuperScreen is a class and not a widget - `declare(null, function(...){})` - constructor was your only choice. See dojo documentation [here](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/_base/declare.html) for more details on declare and dojo classes.
- it would be a widget if it inherited from dijit/_WidgetBase - `declare(_WidgetBase, function(...){})` in which case you would have a choice explained in dojo doc [here](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/understanding_widgetbase/), postCreate() being a favorite (quoting the doc, "by far the most important method to keep in mind...");

The above probably answers your last question: no worry you're indeed just using BorderContainer, not inheriting from it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a great starter project - 
https://github.com/denov/dojo-demo

[HomePage.js](https://github.com/denov/dojo-demo/blob/master/src/main/webapp/js/app/HomePage.js) is pretty close to your SuperScreen.js